# Quick Advice with GUI simple alignment?

Tags: java, user-interface, graphic

I'm new to Java and we got an assignment. I have to create a math frame that does certain operations and has the GUI formatted a certain way. I can do everything except get three textfields stacked on top. Like this:

```
t1
t2
t3
```

these three go down on the left vertically, while the other 4 boxes are across the bottom.

Where the t1, t2 and t3 are textfields and 1, 2, 3 and 4 are the functions of operation.

I can't get the x, y and z to be on the left. Here's my code, please help if you can!

**ConvertFrame.java:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class ConvertFrame extends JFrame {
    private final JLabel prompt; // label to prompt user to enter Fahrenheit
    private final JLabel display; // label to display temperature in Celsius
    private final JTextField temperatureF; // textfield to enter temperature
    private JButton b1;
    private JButton b2;
    private JButton b3;
    private JButton b4;
    private JTextField t1;
    private JTextField t2;
    private JTextField t3;

    private JLabel operation;
    private JLabel equL;

    // constructor sets up GUI
    public ConvertFrame() {
        super("Math Frame");

        prompt = new JLabel("Enter two numbers:");

        operation = new JLabel("        OPR ");
        equL = new JLabel(" = ");

        temperatureF = new JTextField(10); // textfield
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 5));

        b1 = new JButton("ADD");
        b2 = new JButton("SUB");
        b3 = new JButton("MUL");
        b4 = new JButton("CLEAR");

        t1 = new JTextField(7);
        t2 = new JTextField(7);
        t3 = new JTextField(7);

        panel2.add(t1);
        panel2.add(operation);
        panel2.add(t2);
        panel2.add(equL);
        panel2.add(t3);

        panel.add(b1);
        panel.add(b2);
        panel.add(b3);
        panel.add(b4);
        // register anonymous action listener

        Handler1 h1 = new Handler1();
        Handler2 h2 = new Handler2();
        Handler3 h3 = new Handler3();
        Handler4 h4 = new Handler4();

        b1.addActionListener(h1);
        b2.addActionListener(h2);
        b3.addActionListener(h3);
        b4.addActionListener(h4);

        display = new JLabel("");

        add(prompt, BorderLayout.NORTH); // north region
        add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER); // center region
        add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // south region
    } // end ConvertFrame constructor

    private class Handler1 implements ActionListener // anonymous inner class
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String st1 = t1.getText();
            String st2 = t2.getText();
            int x = Integer.parseInt(st1);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(st2);
            int z = x + y;
            String st3 = "";
            st3 = st3 + z;
            t3.setText(st3);

        }
    } //

    private class Handler2 implements ActionListener // anonymous inner class
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String st1 = t1.getText();
            String st2 = t2.getText();
            int x = Integer.parseInt(st1);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(st2);
            int z = x - y;
            String st3 = "";
            st3 = st3 + z;
            t3.setText(st3);

        }
    } // end anonymous inner class

    private class Handler3 implements ActionListener // anonymous inner class
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String st1 = t1.getText();
            String st2 = t2.getText();
            int x = Integer.parseInt(st1);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(st2);
            int z = x * y;
            String st3 = "";
            st3 = Integer.toString(z);

            t3.setText(st3);
        }
    } // end anonymous inner class

    private class Handler4 implements ActionListener // anonymous inner class
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            t1.setText("");
            t2.setText("");
            t3.setText("");
        }
    } // end anonymous inner class

    // end call to addActionListener
} // end class ConvertFrame
```

**Convert.java:**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Convert {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConvertFrame convertFrame = new ConvertFrame();
        convertFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        convertFrame.setSize(500, 400); // set frame size
        convertFrame.setVisible(true); // display frame
    }
} // end class
```

Comment: could you show expected result .?

Comment: It's a GUI that shows up as three textfields on top of each other vertically, so basically three textfields stacked and then ADD SUB MULT CLEAR all horizontal on the bottom.

Comment: Karen, can you sketch something up in Paint to show what the expected outcome is? Or a tool such as https://moqups.com/

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post an image yet (?), but I'll try to explain as well as I can. Three textfields should be stacked on top of each other, but my code puts them in the center - all next to each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to stack textfields on the top

you should change this

```
panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 5));
```

to this

```
panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
```

because in `new GridLayout(row, column)` first argument is row count and next one column count .currently you have 1 row and 5 columns.so text field positioned as coulmns .if you want to position vertically then you should use 1 column and 5 rows

Comment: thank you so much! I'm sorry for overcomplicating the question for that simple of an answer :)

Comment: @Karen so is that you want ?i'm not sure

Comment: @Karen Fast Snail's answer will help you solve your problem. I have provided an alternative using GridBagLayout, you can take a look at it. :)

Comment: GridLayout wouldn't be my first choice as it will force the components to evenly fill the available space as the container is resized, personally I'd use a GridBagLayout with a GridBagConstraint.gridwidth equal to REMAINDER, which will give you an automatic vertical layout, but that's me ;)

Answer (score 3):

**Example Code:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ConvertFrame extends JFrame {

    // Label to prompt user to enter Fahrenheit
    private final JLabel prompt;

    // Label to display temperature in Celsius
    private final JLabel display;

/*  // Textfield to enter temperature
    private final JTextField temperatureF;*/

    // JButtons
    private JButton b1;
    private JButton b2;
    private JButton b3;
    private JButton b4;

    // JTextFields
    private JTextField t1;
    private JTextField t2;
    private JTextField t3;

    private JLabel operation;
    private JLabel equL;

    // constructor sets up GUI
    public ConvertFrame() {
        super("Math Frame");

        prompt = new JLabel("Enter two numbers:");

        operation = new JLabel("OPR");
        equL = new JLabel("=");

        b1 = new JButton("ADD");
        b2 = new JButton("SUB");
        b3 = new JButton("MUL");
        b4 = new JButton("CLEAR");

        t1 = new JTextField(7);
        t2 = new JTextField(7);
        t3 = new JTextField(7);

        // Using GridBagLayout
        JPanel layoutPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 20, 0);
        layoutPanel.add(prompt, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        c.ipadx = 20;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 10, 0);
        layoutPanel.add(t1, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        layoutPanel.add(operation, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        c.ipadx = 20;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 10, 0);
        layoutPanel.add(t2, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        layoutPanel.add(equL, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 5;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        c.ipadx = 20;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 10, 0);
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        layoutPanel.add(t3, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 6;
        c.insets = new Insets(30, 5, 10, 5);
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        layoutPanel.add(b1, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 6;
        c.insets = new Insets(30, 5, 10, 5);
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        layoutPanel.add(b2, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 6;
        c.insets = new Insets(30, 5, 10, 5);
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        layoutPanel.add(b3, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 6;
        c.insets = new Insets(30, 5, 10, 5);
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        layoutPanel.add(b4, c);

        Handler1 h1 = new Handler1();
        Handler2 h2 = new Handler2();
        Handler3 h3 = new Handler3();
        Handler4 h4 = new Handler4();

        b1.addActionListener(h1);
        b2.addActionListener(h2);
        b3.addActionListener(h3);
        b4.addActionListener(h4);

        display = new JLabel("");

        add(layoutPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); // center region

    } // end ConvertFrame constructor

    private class Handler1 implements ActionListener // anonymous inner class
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String st1 = t1.getText();
            String st2 = t2.getText();
            int x = Integer.parseInt(st1);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(st2);
            int z = x + y;
            String st3 = "";
            st3 = st3 + z;
            t3.setText(st3);

            operation.setText("+");
        }
    } //

    private class Handler2 implements ActionListener // anonymous inner class
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String st1 = t1.getText();
            String st2 = t2.getText();
            int x = Integer.parseInt(st1);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(st2);
            int z = x - y;
            String st3 = "";
            st3 = st3 + z;
            t3.setText(st3);

            operation.setText("-");
        }
    } // end anonymous inner class

    private class Handler3 implements ActionListener // anonymous inner class
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String st1 = t1.getText();
            String st2 = t2.getText();
            int x = Integer.parseInt(st1);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(st2);
            int z = x * y;
            String st3 = "";
            st3 = Integer.toString(z);

            t3.setText(st3);

            operation.setText("*");
        }
    } // end anonymous inner class

    private class Handler4 implements ActionListener // anonymous inner class
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            t1.setText("");
            t2.setText("");
            t3.setText("");

            operation.setText("OPR");
        }
    } // end anonymous inner class

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConvertFrame convertFrame = new ConvertFrame();
        convertFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        convertFrame.setSize(500, 400); // set frame size
        convertFrame.setVisible(true); // display frame
    }

} // end class ConvertFrame
```

**Output:**

[image: MathFrame]

**Note:**

- Using [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html), which is a much more flexible layout manager.
- Positioning and re-sizing of components can be done easily using the different attributes of [GridBagConstraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html)
- `c.gridwidth = 4;` for the first 6 components can be replaced with `c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;`